Repeated Prompt in copilot studio Not Triggering Expected Response for Same Input
I'm working with COPILOT STUDIO to retrieve employee attendance data by employee ID. When I enter a prompt like "give me attendance for employee ID 60005218," the bot successfully returns the data on the first try. However, when I repeat the exact same prompt, I get a response saying, "I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to help with that. Can you try rephrasing?"
It seems like the bot doesn’t make a fresh API call or re-evaluate the response when the same input is used consecutively. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Tested different response and output modes (Generated vs. Specific) to no avail.
Has anyone experienced this issue in Copilot studio, and is there a way to force a fresh evaluation of the same prompt?
Additional Details:
I am using Power Automate to fetch data, triggered by the bot.
The initial response is correct, but repeated identical inputs don’t produce the same result.
Any guidance on how to force a fresh response for repeated identical prompts would be appreciated. Thanks!


I'm not familiar with copilot studio but for me it seams you're in "chat mode" so the calls keep your chat history. That would explain, why it is working the first time but then fails. Is there something like "open a new chat" or "get new chat id"?

It is possible that you are hitting rate limits or other errors at the the API that your copilot is calling. This may result in error response. You can enable Debug mode and check why it is failing.

The result of an interaction with an AI model (LLM style) may vary (they can also hallucinate in some situations). This is normal behavior in the context of an LLM usage.
This could be avoided if the tool you are using would support for example a seed number.
Copilot must not be viewed as a 'pilot' it must be viewed as a 'copilot' which can help you but like a human it can be wrong sometimes.
The best to do here (given no seed) is to do what your bot suggest, simply to 'rephrase' and provide additional details to your request. Another option (if available) is to try a different model.
